# Precision and Accuracy

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Given a double, what is the most efficient way to calculate the precision and accuracy of the number? Ideally, I'd like to avoid for loops.

Comment: You mean given a set of data and an expected value?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html

Comment: Well in chemistry, we're learning a very different accuracy and precision. Unfortunately, you will need a for loop to count significant digits.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid for loops?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi That's not true.  OP could use a while loop, but I doubt that's what they're looking for.

Comment: Definitely want to avoid loops if possible

Comment: I don't really understand the math behind it, but you could parse the number as a string and use list comprehension counts relative to the decimal point.

Comment: "1.0" would fail in the given case. Understanding the math behind it would be a lot more valuable going forward.

Comment: I took a look at the link, but I'm lost. Perhaps, you can explain.

Comment: You can't even consider precision and accuracy without a reference - a single `double` doesn't really have either. For example, if your "correct" value is `1.01`, but if your measure is only precise to one decimal place, you might measure `1.0`. A more precise measure might come up with `1.009`. On the other hand, measuring `12.123456789` is very precise, but highly inaccurate... In other words, you need to provide quite a bit more information before "precision" and "accuracy" even become meaningful concepts in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Floating point numbers are stored in binary in python. Accuracy and precision have *totally different* implications in binary, especially given that computers are constrained to fixed-length representations. You can demonstrate that to yourself simply by noting that the code `1e16+1 == 1e16` returns `True`.

You linked to Wolfram.com where precision and accuracy are discussed in terms of **decimal numbers**. It means nothing to talk about the position of the decimal point in a number stored in a computer in binary. To represent and manipulate decimal numbers with their *real decimal precision and accuracy*, you need to use python's `Decimal` class.

Note that you must give the Decimal class a string for it to be accurate in decimal terms. If you give it a literal number (e.g. `Decimal(1.001)`) you are just giving it a float, and the Decimal you create will be the precise decimal representation of python's imprecise floating point representation of 1.001.

Sadly, the Decimal class doesn't have methods to return the number of digits either side of the decimal point. However, assuming your decimal is in decimal form, you can just examine it as a string, using `str(x)` where `x` is an instance of `Decimal`.